# Replacing strings in R based on numbers before string

Tags: r, string, text, replace, conditional-statements

Assume I have the following code (240 occurrences of the same pattern).

```
<description>some02text01</description>
<class>selzoom</class>
<title>more text</title>
<explanation />
```

I want to replace `<explanation />` with `<explanation>02</explanation>`, depending on the Number **before** `text01`.

What I tried so far:
Extracting the numbers from the description line:

```
list <- inputtext %>%
  xml_find_all("//description") %>%
  as_list() %>%
  unlist()

list <- list[1:240]

results <- c()
for (i in list) {
  results <- c(results, str_extract(i, "\\d\\d(?=te)"))
}
```

Put a placeholder in the `<explanation />` line, so it's now:
`<explanation>NN</explanation>`

Then I did `str_replace_all(inputtext, "NN", results)`. But it returns

```
Warning message:
In stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

But when I do `sum(!!str_count(inputtext, "NN"))` it's the same value as the length of `results`.

Any idea where the problem is?

Comment: please include your entire code

Answer (score 0):

The answer below assumes that you're reading in lines and that each line is read into "explanation_list" variable.  (In your question, you use the variable name "list" which is ambiguous with the R data type "list").  The number is extracted and saved into a variable "num" and a data.frame of original and modified lines.

```
explanation_frame <- data.frame(line=character(0),
                                num=numeric(0),
                                new_line=character(0))
explanation_list <- list()

explanation_list[[length(explanation_list)+1]] <- "<description>some02text01</description>
<class>selzoom</class>
<title>more text</title>
<explanation />"

for (i in 1:length(explanation_list)) {
  num <- gsub("^[[:alpha:][:cntrl:]<>/]+(\\d+)te.*$","\\1",explanation_list[i])
  new_line <- gsub("<explanation />",paste0("<explanation>",num,"</explanation>"),explanation_list[i])
  
  if (is.na(as.numeric(num))) num <- ""
  
  explanation_frame <- rbind(explanation_frame,
                            data.frame(line=explanation_list[i],
                                       num=as.numeric(num),
                                       new_line=new_line))
}

explanation_frame$new_line
```

Comment: added code to make clear what list means.

Comment: Your intentions were clear in the original post, and my answer will still work.  The point I was making is that "list" is not the best choice for a variable name because the R function and data type is also called "list".  So in your example if you later try to create a new list object, eg "x <- list()" you'll get an error because you've overwritten the base function with variable name in your current environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
library(stringr)

t <- gregexpr("\\d+text" , x)
number <- str_sub(x , t[[1]] , t[[1]] + attr(t[[1]] , "match.length") - 5)

sub("<explanation />" , paste0("<explanation>" , number , "</explanation>") , x)
```

- output

```
[1] "<description>some02text01</description>\n
<class>selzoom</class>\n<title>more text</title>\n
<explanation>02</explanation>"
```

- data

```
x <- "<description>some02text01</description>
<class>selzoom</class>
<title>more text</title>
<explanation />"
```